# Difficulty in synchronizing scrolling between a canvas with and the rest of the page content

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js

I'm currently working on a project that involves a Three.js canvas with OrbitControls for interactive 3D visualization. However, I'm facing difficulty in synchronizing scrolling between the Three.js canvas and the rest of the page content.

The issue is that while I can scroll through the page content outside the canvas, scrolling inside the canvas using OrbitControls only affects the zooming along the z-axis of the 3D scene, but it doesn't scroll the entire page. What I want to achieve is synchronized scrolling between the canvas and the page content, so that when I scroll inside the canvas, it also scrolls the entire page content, and vice versa.

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { alpha: true } );
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 );
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  scene.background = null;
    document.getElementById('canvas').appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    controls.enableZoom = true;

    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(cube);

    camera.position.z = 5;

    function animate() {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
      cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
    animate();
```

```css
 body {
      margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    #container {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      overflow-y: auto;
      perspective: 1000px;
    }
    canvas {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      z-index: 999999;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    .content {
      padding: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Scrolling Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi.</p>
    <!-- Add more content here -->
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For achieving the desired effect I took a different approach where the canvas remains transparent and its interactivity is disabled while manipulating the camera position on the y-axis based on the scroll.

To summarize, I've set the pointer-events of the canvas to none, allowing content underneath to be interacted with. Additionally, I've made the canvas transparent and set its clear colour to transparent as well:

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 0);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
scene.background = null;
```

Then, on scroll, I am updating the y-axis position of the camera relative to the scroll amount:

```
function onWindowScroll() {
  const yaxisvalue = window.pageYOffset;
  const scrolly = -(yaxisvalue / 20);
  camera.position.set(0, 0, scrolly);
}
```

This solution provides a visually appealing effect while maintaining performance and ensuring the interactivity of underlying elements. A nice compromise.